# Search a word in all Common Crawl WARC files

Tags: amazon-s3, solr, common-crawl, warc, large-data

I want to search a word (for example a company name) in all the WARC files(nearly 36K warc files) from common crawl and get all the urls having that company name in its HTML source content.

And I want to keep those WARC files in S3 itself. Just I need the urls from those WARC files as result.

Is there any modules or pre-built packages available for this?

May I use Solr indexing? (but it may need more memory)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you just search the web for warc and Solr, you get at least one answer (e.g. [webarchive-discovery](https://github.com/ukwa/webarchive-discovery)). Have you tried that first?

Comment: Using https://github.com/ukwa/webarchive-discovery we can index the WARC files which are stored in our local system but not in S3. Right?